# How can i show UIViewControllerRepresentable screen on button tap from UIViewRepresentable

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I am working on a SwiftUI project, in my app i have to show a map, i am able to show map using `UIViewRepresentable`, now that map view will have a button and on tapping on that button mapview will needs to show controller (full screen direction) view and i know i can do this using `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

I need help in which how can i show the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` from button click of `UIViewRepresentable`

Till now what i have done is, adding my code :

On button click i am calling `showDetailMap`  function which calls the `MapDetailViewController` , but some how `MapDetailViewController` is not opening as model.

```
private func showDetailMap() {
    MapDetailViewController()
}

struct MapDetailViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MapDetailViewController {
    let viewController: MapDetailViewController = MapDetailViewController()
    return viewController
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MapDetailViewController, context: Context) {}


}
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
     @State var isPresentVC = false
    
     var body: some View {
     
           ZStack {
                Button("OpenMapVC") {
                    isPresentVC = true
                }
                
            }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentVC, content: {
               MapDetailViewController()
            })
       }
  }
```